# AJAX Method not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form, when i click on submit i dont want the page to refresh, thats why i added AJAX to achieve this as you can see. The problem is that its not working.

```
 <form id="formFooter" action="" method="post">

            <h3>Select your trademark</h3>

                <select class="form-control" name="trademark">

                    <option></option>
                    <option>©</option>
                    <option>™</option>
                    <option>®</option>

                </select>

            <h3>Your company name</h3>

                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" />

                <h3>Background Color</h3>


                <input class="form-control" placeholder="(e.g. 00ff00)" type="text" name="backgroundColor">

                <h3>Font Color</h3>


                <input class="form-control" placeholder="(e.g. 00ff00)" type="text" name="fontColor">


                <h3>Opacity</h3>


                <input class="form-control" placeholder="(Pick a value between 0 and 1 e.g. 0.3)" type="text" name="opacity">


                <br/>
                <br/>


                <button class="form-control" id="run" type="submit" name="submit">Generate footer</button>
                </form>
            <div id="showData">&nbsp;</div>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                     $('#run').on("click", function (e) {
                        var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
                        $.ajax({
                        url: "script.php",
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#showData').html(data);
                            },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                        });
                        return false;
                    });

                </script>
```

Here is the script.php:

```
<?php
function footerPreview ()
{
echo "<h3>Preview:</h3>";
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$trademark = $_POST["trademark"];
$company = $_POST["companyName"];       
$date = date("Y");
//style
$backgroundColor = $_POST['backgroundColor']; 
$fontColor = $_POST['fontColor']; 
$opacity =  $_POST['opacity']; 

echo "<div id='generated_footer_date' style='background-color:$backgroundColor; color:$fontColor; opacity: $opacity; ' >$trademark $date $company </div>";          

}


// generate result for the head
function rawHead()
{
$head = htmlspecialchars('<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200" rel="stylesheet">
</head>',ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<pre><h4>Put this code inside your head tags</h4>$head</pre>";
}



// generate result for the body
function rawBody ()
{
$body1of5 = htmlspecialchars('<div id="footer_date">',ENT_QUOTES);
$body2of5 = $_POST["trademark"];
$body3of5 = date("Y");          
$body4of5 = $_POST["companyName"];
$body5of5 = htmlspecialchars('</div>',ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<pre><h4>Put this code inside your body tags</h4>$body1of5 $body2of5 $body3of5 $body4of5 $body5of5 </pre>";
}

// generate result for the CSS
function rawCSS () 
{
$opacity =  $_POST['opacity']; 
$backgroundColor = $_POST['backgroundColor'];
$fontColor = $_POST['fontColor'];
echo 
"<pre>
<h4>Put this code in your websites stylesheet</h4>
color:$fontColor;
background-color:$backgroundColor;
opacity:$opacity;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
padding-top:15px;
height:50px;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
position:fixed; 
</pre>";

}


// Generate eveything by one click

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
footerPreview();
rawHead();
rawBody();
rawCSS();
}

?>
```

When i click on submit nothing happens. I want the script.php to be generate on the same page without refreshing.

Comment: why r u using `contentType: false,`? please add the complete form here

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: What error are you getting check console .

Comment: In case you're un aware, press F12 to open your debugger in your web browser - the console is there.

Comment: No errors in the console @MarkPhillips

Comment: dont know why are u trying like that, and also, what is the purpose to use FormDate here, you dont have file input here

Comment: just replace `var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);` with
        `var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();`

Comment: if u dont get any error in console than add `print_r($_POST)` in your php file at top

Comment: Shove a javascript alert("hello world!"); into your JS code, ensure it's firing at all.

Comment: @MarkPhillips its showing

Comment: Great good start, Next I would recommend what @devpro suggested.

Comment: @MarkPhillips: you are going right bro,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You can make it very simple your Ajax Request as:*

First of all no need to use FormDate here, because you don't have any `file` input in your `<form>`, so you can use `serialize()` data in your request as:

```
var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
```

Second, you are just printing the HTML in your PHP, it means you just need to print html, so you can use `dataType=HTML` here as:

```
dataType: "html",
```

Third, one more thing will help you in debugging, add `print_r($_POST)` in your `script.php` file at top and check the console.

**Modified Request:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#run").click(function(){
        var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data:  formData,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response)
            {
                $('#showData').html(response);
            },
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                //any loader
            }
        });
        return false;
   }); 
});
```

**Update:**

> From your comment:  yeah it shows after submit. It shows this : Array
>   ( [trademark] => [companyName] => [backgroundColor] => [fontColor] =>
>   [opacity] => ) – Kevin Aartsen 6 mins ago

Look at this array, you don't have `submit` in the result of `$_POST` so you have two options to change this:

1) You can use `count()` function for checking `if(count($_POST) > 0)`.

2) Or you can use `<input type='submit' name='submit'>` instead of `<button type='submit' name='submit'>`

Comment: it does work now kind of. it doesn't show the desired result but it does show the print_r you told me to add on top of my php file

Comment: Great, now you have the data you need you can parse it correctly in PHP :)

Comment: @KevinAartsen: this is good to know, your ajax is working fine now, now add your input in your PHP file correctly.

Comment: @KevinAartsen: is `submit` included in `print_r($_POST)` result?

Comment: yeah it shows after submit. It shows this : Array ( [trademark] => [companyName] => [backgroundColor] => [fontColor] => [opacity] => )

Comment: look at this you dont have submit in your array @KevinAartsen, it means, this condition will not work `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: @KevinAartsen: now u have two solutions, `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` replace with `if(count($_POST) > 0)` or use `<input type='submit'>` instead of `<button>`

Comment: @KevinAartsen: glad to help u bro, this is good hobby to debug step by step.

Answer (score 1):

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#run').on("click", function (e) {
                   e.preventDefault();
                   alert('inside ajax call');
                   var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
                   $.ajax({
                   url: "script.php",
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: formData,
                   success: function (data) {
                       $('#showData').html(data);
                       alert('ajax call success');
                   },
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false
                   });
                   return false;
               });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formFooter" action="" method="post">

    <h3>Select your trademark</h3>
        <select class="form-control" name="trademark">
            <option></option>
            <option>©</option>
            <option>™</option>
            <option>®</option>
        </select>
    <h3>Your company name</h3>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" placeholder="Your company name" />
    <h3>Background Color</h3>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="(e.g. 00ff00)" type="text" name="backgroundColor">
    <h3>Font Color</h3>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="(e.g. 00ff00)" type="text" name="fontColor">
    <h3>Opacity</h3>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="(Pick a value between 0 and 1 e.g. 0.3)" type="text" name="opacity">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <button class="form-control" id="run" type="submit" name="submit">Generate footer</button>
    </form>
    <div id="showData">&nbsp;</div>
```

try above code and remove alert when it works for you :)